# How would I go about creating this many-to-many relationship in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So, I have the following 3 classes:

> **User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Timezone Timezone { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserChannel> UserChannels { get; set; }
}
```

> **Channel.cs**

```
public class Channel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Channel")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> **UserChannel.cs**

```
public class UserChannel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; }
}
```

`UserChannel` is the medium between `User` and `Channel`.

The `UserChannels` table looks like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| Id | UserId | ChannelId |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Both `UserId` and `ChannelId` are foreign keys, for the `User` and `Channel` class.

Now, to get which `Channels` belong to a user, I would have to write something like this:

```
using var context = new TwitchContext();
var me = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
var myChannels = me.UserChannels.Select(x => x.Channel);
```

Is there a way I can just get a collection of `Channel` directly instead of using `UserChannel`?

Comment: Is this a many-to-many relationship? Else a simple navigation property (`ICollection<Channel>`) should suffice.

Comment: Many-to-many without an intermediary entity isn't supported in EF Core yet unfortunately, although it was in EF 6.

Comment: are you trying to achieve a one to many or a many to many relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many to many relationship without referencing the join table / entity won't be available until EF Core 5 comes out, as per current roadmap:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#many-to-many-navigation-properties-aka-skip-navigations

Feature request is tracked by this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19003

that is included in EF Core 5.0.0 milestone.

EF Core 5 release is planned for November 2020.

Answer (score 2):

In EF.Core, many-to-many without a join table is [not yet supported](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1368). So you will need to rely on the solution with the `UserChannel` class and the `Select` call for now.

As your example does not explicitly specify that a channel can have multiple users, a one-to-many solution with a `ICollection<Channel>` property might work as well.

Comment: A channel can have many users, so it is many-to-many. So you have answered my question. Thanks!